# remote git repo cannot be auto checkout after a merge hook

Tags: linux, git, version-control

I have a remote non-bare git repo, which is my static blog site.
I push a commit in **local `master`** branch to the **remote `master`** branch every time, and there is a **`post-update`** hook, which is like below:

```
echo "hook..."
git merge master
echo "after hook..."
```

In the remote repo, there is a *`pages`* branch which is checked out by default, what I want is that `pages` branch keep update of the `master` branch and auto checkout to workspace.

However, workspace cannot be checkout automatically, but the two branch has been updated.

In sum, What I want is the workspace can update after the *`pages`* branch merged every time. So that my website can update too.

```
==========detail process===========

==local repo:  
*master


==remote repo:  
*pages  
 master
```

1. `git push local-master ---> remote-master`  [OK]
2. trigger hook do : `git merge master` to `pages` branch (which is checked out) [OK]
3. workspace updated (this is what I want) [NOT-OK]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the current working directory of such an hook is the `.git/` folder itself (ie, `GIT_DIR` is set to '`.`', which in non-bare repo is `.git/`), try a `.git/hooks/post-receive` with:

```
unset GIT_DIR
cd ..
git merge master
```

Comment: Thanks!I'll try later!

Comment: @ghuizhang Again, don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer for your other questions.